# Как получить данных из бд

Tags: php, python, база-данных

Всем привет, у меня тут проблемка возникла 
У меня есть сайт, где покупаешь подписку на программу 
Собственно после покупки данные записываются в бд
И теперь вопрос у меня возник как программа будет узнавать есть ли у человека подписка или нет 
ТК на сколько я знаю, если просто подключить к программе базу данных (ввести айпи, логин, пароль ТД..),то это не безопасно
Программа на python 
Как сделать мне безопасную авторизацию в программе?
Заранее спасибо, обнял подкинул!

Comment: Используйте Rest API или GraphQL

Answer (score 0):

Ну никто вам не мешает создавать уникальный токен и попросить авторизоваться в программе заново + ввести уникальный токен, который выдали при покупке подписки. Способов куча..

Comment: @Php help pls Смотря о какой безопасности вы задумываетесь, дополните свой вопрос, возможно даже со схемой вашего приложения. В остальном, он очень абстрактен и способов решения, как уже сказано, куча.